# TortoiseHg 3 on windows10: context menu displaying but not working

Tags: contextmenu, windows-10, tortoisehg

I have installed TortoiseHg 3.4.1 on a windows 10 machine.
Everything is working fine, but the explorer extension: context menu correctly show up, but nothing happens when clicked. According to some tips, I updated to the last version (3.7.1), but stil I get the problem.

Any suggestions to correct the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Update to latest release (3.7.1) at least

Comment: Updated to release 3.7.1: still same behavior